# How can I detect mobile device in Blogger Post?

Tags: mobile, blogger

Is there way to detect mobile device in Blogger Post without using JavaScript? We can do it in blogger template easily using primitives (i.e. cond=data:mobile) but I couldn't find a way in post.

Answer (score 3):

Blogger Conditional tags only work in templates and not on posts/widgets.

If you want something for a particular url in mobile site,

use conditional url tags `<b:if cond='data:blog.url == PUT_URL_HERE'>`

and

mobile conditional tag `<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == data:blog.isMobile'>`

together.